# POST DATA , and get answer in c#

Tags: c#, post, get

i have big problem in posting data to php (because  im newbie in c# )

ok

i want send this request to server

```
string Parameters = "hwid=" + _serialNo + "&country=" + PcIp + "&nat=1&pcname=" + PcName + "&winver=" + str;
```

and after sending data to server get activation key ,

in my server side i used simple php + mysql 
get Parameters , check it , then show me code 
this code check user

```
if (mysql_query($sql)) {echo "done1";
            } else {echo "err211";}
```

if c# program get done1 , get this code

```
$sql = "SELECT `key` FROM `clients` WHERE `hwid` = '".dRead("hwid")."';";
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
                echo mysql_result($res, 0);
```

and if c# program get key , start working

ok where is my problem ?

i cant write program for sending data , 
i read many blog but none of them explain me who to POST data , and get response :(

so please some one teach me ,

Answer (score 2):

HttpWebRequest allows you to set the verb in the request

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://host/page.php?"+Parameters);
myRequest.Method = "POST";
```

If you're not sending any other data, then you should just be able to call `myRequest.GetResponse` and read the results from that.

Answer (score 0):

simply, [WebClient.UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx):

```
    NameValueCollection fields = new NameValueCollection();
    fields.Add("a","b");
    fields.Add("c","d");
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] resp = client.UploadValues(address, fields);
        // use Encoding to get resp as a string if needed
    }
```